# how to prove if $\det A=\det B$ then $A=CB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be invertible $n \times n$- matrices and $C$ be an $n \times n$- matrix with $\det C =1$. Prove that $\det A = \det B$ if and only if $A=CB$.

I've got the proof backward but I got stuck on the forward. I got some hints like expressing those matrices with elementary matrices, but I failed to find anything useful.

I just don't know how to prove "if $\det A = \det B$ then $A=CB$".

ps.thanks for all clarifications and that was just my understanding. This is the original question and I'm also confused about it.

Let $A$ and $B$ be invertible $n \times n$- matrices. Prove that $\det A = \det B$ if and only if $A=CB$, where $C$ is an $n \times n$- matrix such that $\det C =1$.

Comment: It is not true when $det A = det B = 0$. But for invertible matrices, clearly $C = AB^{-1}$ works.

Comment: @OP do you have to prove this assertion $\mathrm{det}(AB) = \mathrm{det}(A)\mathrm{det}(B)$ or can you assume that?

Comment: When you write \methrm{det}A then you see $\mathrm{det}A$ without proper spacing, but when you write \det A then you see $\det A$.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I disapprove of this way of using the word "where".  That word should explain notation or conventions, thus $abc = def$ where $a$ is the temperature and $b$ is the price of eggs, etc.  In this case it appears that "where $C$ is a $n\times n$ matrix" means "FOR SOME $n\times n$ matrix $C$.  Whether it means "for some" or "for every" is something the reader may fail to know. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The Statement is obviously false, it implies that there is only one Matrix C with determinant 1

Comment: why there is only one matrix C with determinant 1?

Comment: Just consider a different matrix $D$ with $\det D = 1$ then by the same argument as for $C$: $A = DB$ and thus $ D= AB^{-1}=C$

Comment: @john well I understand your point. For specific $A$ and $B$, there exactly only one $C$ which satisfies the statement. But $A$ and $B$ are not specific...

Comment: Then maybe I don't speak the same language. When I say: Let $A,B$ be two matrices they are two fixed matrices.

Comment: @MaggieMak:  The correct statement, which was more closely approximated by the original Question, is that if $\det A = \det B \neq 0$ (for matrices $A,B$ of equal dimension), then there exists a matrix $C$ with $\det C = 1$ such that $A = CB$.  In the usual understanding, you have specified matrices $A,B,C$ and then predicate a relation $A=CB$ only on the equality of determinants $\det A = \det B$, which is clearly unsupportable.

Comment: @MaggieMak if the statements holds for $A,B,C$ then it must also hold for $A,B,D$, do you understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $C:=AB^{-1}$, which is possible since $B$ is invertible. Then

$$CB=(AB^{-1})B=A(B^{-1}B)=AI=A$$ and

$$\det(C)=\det(A)\det(B^{-1})=\frac{\det(A)}{\det(B)}=1$$

Comment: Er..what are you proving? I don't think we can assume A=CB

Comment: @Mathgemini: Use $DetADetA^{-1}=DetId=1$ to show $DetC=1$.

Comment: OK, if $C=AB^{-1}$, what **can** we say about $CB$ ??

Comment: @GEdgar He literally answers that question in his answer.

Comment: @avid: thanks.  that was in an edit after Maggie doubted it, and after I asked her what can she say about $CB$.